# CSS BEM - Class for SVG

Tags: html, css, svg, sass, bem

I'm trying to use[BEM](https://en.bem.info/methodology/quick-start/) style for my SASS/CSS files. Everything works fine, but I have problems styling SVG files.

BEM says that there should be no tag or ID selector, only class selectors. However, I want to give my SVGs different colors and sometimes different widths and heights.

Currently I can only do this with a tag selector like this:

```
block__icon {
    height: 36px;
    width: 36px;

    svg {
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      fill: #fff;
      fill-opacity: .8;
    }
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="block__icon">
   <svg ...></svg>
</div>
```

Do you know a better way?

Comment: you can also add classes to your svg tags: `<svg class="svg__icon">`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can remove the div and style the svg directly. With the modifiers you can change the appearance of the svg like the color or size:

```
<svg class="block__icon block__icon--large"></svg>
```

I would structure the css for it like this:

```
.block {
  &__icon {
    height: 36px;
    width: 36px;
    fill: #fff;
    fill-opacity: .8;

    &--color-blue {
      color: blue;
    }

    &--large {
      height: 72px;
      width: 72px;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well... You can get rid of the element level css for this particular case....

`width: 100%, height: 100%` can be moved to **normalize.css/reset.css** where you write the element level css.

Further the `fill: #fff; fill-opacity: .8;` ca be replaced with `color: currentColor;` in **normalize.css/reset.css**.

**Normalize.css**

```
svg {
    color: currentColor;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

Now you can add `color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8)` in **.block__icon**.

Also you can use the **viewbox** property in svg in case you need to play with size of the icon to render.

What I would suggest is: it is completely fine to use element level css if the svg tag is not in your control to add class to it. No matter how strong the methodology is, there are exceptions to everything. :)